# What is a good, "Pythonic" Ajax datagrid for the web?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datagrid

I have been working with a few Ajax datagrids for an application where inline editing, sorting, moving / resizing / hiding / showing columns, and search by field are desired, and have so far found that the options I've tried don't work, at least not well. Flexigrid requires customization and runs into cross-browser issues; jqGrid does not furnish useful examples (*read: you need PHP4 and a not provided MySQL database to run their examples*), and ExtJS has support but not entirely competent support (*the tech support guy had no idea how to read HTML with Unix line breaks and told me my code was weird and all on one line*). I haven't yet investigated Dhtmlx grid too far; the demo looks nice but I have no idea whether that means it's actually nice to work with.

What are the best options for a datagrid with inline editing, sorting, moving / resizing / hiding / showing columns? I'd ideally like something "Pythonic", with a gentle learning curve, and not a bear to get working cross-browser (or just working).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems like you're not adverse to using jQuery or a similar library, I'll recommend - http://www.datatables.net/

REALLY good examples, REALLY good API, REALLY good cross browser suppport. Plus it can use themeroller with very little muss. So if you're like me and you hate fiddling with CSS it's perfect.

Comment: Thank you; I almost asked for something that would work with jQuery as well.

Comment: And if its worth anything, I am a python/django dev and I'd consider it quite "pythonic" :D

Comment: Now you really have my attention. (-:

Comment: Just make sure you accept and upvote if the answer was helpful!